# symfony redirect loses parameter

Tags: php, symfony1

I have a symfony 1.4 project with this routing rule in my main application:

```
registration_profilechoice:
  url: register/profiles/:restricted_data
  param: { module: register, action: profileChoices, restricted_data: nonrestricted }
```

In the index action for this module I am trying to redirect to `register/profiles/restricted` using

```
$this->redirect("register/profiles/restricted");
```

Looking at the log, the above command results in this:

```
{sfFrontWebController} Redirect to "https://mdm-dev1.stanford.edu/client.php/register/profiles"
```

What happened to the `restricted` parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not supposed to hard code URLs like that, that's the whole purpose of having a routing system... you can change the URL without changing all your links.

```
$this->redirect('@registration_profilechoice?restricted_data=restricted');
```